# Adding values based on levels of a factor

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have this reproducible `data.frame` representing UTM locations for five individuals (`IndID`), each of which have 20 locations

**EDIT:** The different answers seem to result from running my `for()` loop on the unsorted `data.frame.` I have added code to `arrange` the df by `IndID` and now get the same answers as you.

```
library(plyr)

set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"), 20),
                UTM_E = sample(482000:509000, 100),
                UTM_N = sample(4780000:4810500, 100)
                    )

Data <- arrange(Data, IndID)
```

And I also have this table containing a single `Start` location for each individual.

```
set.seed(123)
Start <- data.frame(IndID = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"),
                UTM_E = sample(482000:509000, 5),
                UTM_N = sample(4780000:4810500, 5)
                    )
```

For each level of IndID I want to apply the following calculation to add a new column in `Data.` For example, when `Data$IndID == Start$IndID` I want to create

```
Data$NewValue = ((((Data$UTM_E - Start$UTM_E)/1000)^2) + (((Data$UTM_N - Start$UTM_N)/1000)^2))
```

While I know this is possible with the following `for()` loop and formatting code, I suspect there is a better vector approach that would be much cleaner and more efficient.

```
Inds <- unique(Data$IndID)
NewValue <- list()
for (i in 1:length(Inds)){
    NewValue[[i]] = ((((Data$UTM_E[Data$IndID == Inds[i]] - Start$UTM_E[i])/1000)^2) + 
            (((Data$UTM_N[Data$IndID == Inds[i]] - Start$UTM_N[i])/1000)^2))
                    }

Data$NewValue <- c(do.call("cbind",NewValue)) 

head(Data)
tail(Data)
```

Any suggestions on how to 'vectorize' the above `for()` loop would be appreciated.

Comment: A side-note: if you are analysing animal movement, you may have a look at the  `adehabitatLT` package. Very easy to get basic metrics from spatiotemporal data like yours. See e.g. [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitatLT/vignettes/adehabitatLT.pdf).

Comment: @Henrik.  Yes, the adehabitatLT package is great, but for the current project working out of the ltraj object format is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `merge` to make one data.frame, then vectorise from there:

```
data2 <- merge(Data, Start, by = "IndID")
data2$NewValue <- ((data2$UTM_E.x - data2$UTM_E.y)/1000)^2 + 
                  ((data2$UTM_N.x - data2$UTM_N.y)/1000)^2
```

Comment: Were you able to get the same values as the OP though? Im getting the same as your and very different from his. This is why I didnt post.

Comment: oh, you are right - The first and last values are the same which is all I checked

Comment: "Call me only found another orphan"

Comment: @David Arenburg They are the same - the rows are just in a different order

Comment: Its impossible. I've created `NewValue2` after OPs `NewValue` in order to compare. And they didn't match by row.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `data.table`s binary join and update by reference capabilities for the task

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(Data), IndID)[Start, NewValue := ((UTM_E - i.UTM_E)/1e3)^2 + 
                                              ((UTM_N - i.UTM_N)/1e3)^2]
```

*Note* me and @jeremycg getting different results from yours. It seems like you have some error in your calculations.

---

The idea here is to key by the common column. the perform a binary join, and while joining update the `NewValue` column in place using `:=`. The `i.` before the column names is meant to distinguish between the same columns in `Data` and `Start`